# how to keep appending the list of values of a column until we get a new value in another column?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to keep appending a list of values to lookaheadRunInfo.gerrits until I get a new lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink in the while loop,I tried to create a variable “ECJoblink_previous” to capture the previous ECJoblink and create a new list only when they are different and keep appending until ECJoblink_previous changes,I tried as below but its not working,what am I missing?

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
    conn.Open();

    string sql = @"some query";
    var ECJoblink_previous ="";    
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(rdr[0] + " -- " + rdr[1]);
        //Console.ReadLine();
        lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink = rdr.GetString(0);
        if (ECJoblink_previous == lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink)
        {
            //Keep appending the list of gerrits until we get a new lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink
            var gerritList = new List<String>();
            lookaheadRunInfo.gerrits = gerritList.Add(rdr.GetString(2));
        }
        ECJoblink_previous = lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink;
        lookaheadRunInfo.UserSubmitted = rdr.GetString(2);
        lookaheadRunInfo.SubmittedTime = rdr.GetString(3).ToString();
        lookaheadRunInfo.RunStatus = "null";
        lookaheadRunInfo.ElapsedTime = (DateTime.UtcNow - rdr.GetDateTime(3)).ToString();
        lookaheadRunsInfo.Add(lookaheadRunInfo);
    }

    rdr.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var lookaheadRunsInfo = new List<LookaheadRunInfo>();
LookAheadRunInfo lookaheadRunInfo;
var i = 0;
var ecJoblink_previous = string.Empty;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    if (rdr.GetString(0) != ecJoblink_previous)
    {
        ecJoblink_previous = rdr.GetString(0);

        if (i > 0)
        {
             lookaheadRunsInfo.Add(lookaheadRunInfo);
        }

        // Create a new lookaheadRunInfo
        lookaheadRunInfo = new lookaheadRunInfo
        {
            ECJobLink = rdr.GetString(0),
            UserSubmitted = rdr.GetString(2),
            SubmittedTime = rdr.GetString(3).ToString(),
            RunStatus = "null",
            ElapsedTime = (DateTime.UtcNow - rdr.GetDateTime(3)).ToString(),
            gerrits = new List<string>
            {
                rdr.GetString(2)
            }
        };
    }
    else
    {
        //Keep appending the list of gerrits until we get a new lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink
        lookaheadRunInfo.gerrits.Add(rdr.GetString(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: then it throws an error `gerritList.Add(rdr.GetString(2));` at saying gerritlist doesnot exist in current context,also `gerritList.Add(rdr.GetString(2));` doesnt look right?

Comment: Try again now, Jeff, I updated my answer. You do need the "else" block of course since you are using the same "lookaheadRunInfo" instance within the loop.

Comment: line gerritList.Add(rdr.GetString(2)); is throwing error Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>',also updated the question with latest code

Comment: There is another error: You are setting "var ECJoblink_previous = lookaheadRunInfo.ECJobLink" in every "rdr.read()" loop, so it has no chance to ever change. :)

Comment: You want to "collect" the GetString(2) until GetString(0) changes, right? So separate the "collection" from creating and adding a new instance of "lookaheadRunInfo". You want "UserSubmitted" = the last gerrit from the collected gerrits? Are you sure?

Comment: doesnt your answer cover that?

Comment: this wouldn't work as when there is a new EC link he needs to instatiate and add the corresponding gerrit aswell

Comment: Updated my answer again, just to show you the way, didn't test it.